# Rails: route helpers for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested resources as below:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end
```

According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html),

> You can also use url_for with a set of objects, and Rails will automatically determine which route you want:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Ad details', url_for([@magazine, @ad]) %>
> ```
>
> In this case, Rails will see that @magazine is a Magazine and @ad is an Ad and will therefore use the magazine_ad_path helper. In helpers like link_to, you can specify just the object in place of the full url_for call:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Ad details', [@magazine, @ad] %>
> ```
>
> For other actions, you just need to insert the action name as the first element of the array:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Edit Ad', [:edit, @magazine, @ad] %>
> ```

In my case, I have the following code which was fully functional:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category_id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category_id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category_id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Obviously it is a little too verbose and I wanted to shorten it using the trick mentioned above from rails guides.

But if I changed the *Show* and *Edit* link as follows:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [product, product.category_id] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, product, product.category_id] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category_id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Neither of them works any more, and the pages complains the same thing:

```
NoMethodError in Products#index
Showing /root/Projects/foo/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `persisted?' for 3:Fixnum
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Does it work if you do `[product, product.category]`  (for the 'Show' url)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way Rails is 'automagically' knowing which path to use is by inspecting the objects you pass for their classes, and then looking for a controller whose name matches. So you need to make sure that what you are passing to the `link_to` helper is the actual model object, and not something like `category_id` which is just a `fixnum` and therefore has no associated controller.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [product.category, product] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, product.category, product] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [product.category, product], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks your explanation totally makes sense! The first two works perfectly, except for the last one and it should be `<%= link_to 'Destroy', [product.category, product], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`, or it will turn to **delete_category_product_path** which doesn't exist.

Comment: Doh! Edited to reflect that!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the offending line is one of these:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', [product, product.category_id] %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, product, product.category_id] %></td>
```

The `product.category_id` is a `Fixnum` and the routing can't know that a random number is supposed to map to `category_id`.

Use the previous URLs you had, they're more readable.